# AngularJS passing HTML into $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, http

I have these files:

**index.html**

```
//contains logic about passing arguments to the app.js btnClick function
<div ng-bind-html="currentDisplay"></div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.factory('oneFac', function ($http){
var htmlCode = null;
htmlCode = $http.get("one.html").then(function (response){
    return response.data;
});
    return htmlCode;
});

app.factory('twoFac', function ($http){
var htmlCode = null;
htmlCode = $http.get("two.html").then(function (response){
    return response.data;
});
    return htmlCode;
});

app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, oneFac, twoFac, $sce){
  $scope.one = oneFac;
  $scope.two = twoFac;
  $scope.currentDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.one);
  $scope.btnClick = function (selection){
    if(selection == "one"){
      $scope.currentDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.one);
    }
    else if(selection == "two"){
      $scope.currentDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.two);
    }
  }
});
```

**one.html**

```
<p>one</p>
```

**two.html**

```
<p>two</p>
```

*How could I get the HTML into the $scope then have it inserted into the html?*

I am getting an error saying $sce requires a string argument, but I thought what I am passing to it should be a string.

Comment: try using `ng-bind-html` or `ng-include` if you only need to load html files

Comment: Sorry, I actually already had this in the code, but I understand the ng-include part, but these two views can't be on the html page at the same time.

Comment: maybe take a look at the example at the bottom of the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oneFac and twoFac are promises, not strings. You need to wait until the promises resolve to get the strings:

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $q, oneFac, twoFac, $sce){
  // waiting until both are resolved, then setting the rest of the controller.
  // You may still want to initialize part of the controller before your promises resolve
  // change accordingly
  $q.all([oneFac, twoFac]).then(function (promises) {
    var oneHtml = promises[0],
        twoHtml = promises[1];

    $scope.one = oneHtml;
    $scope.two = twoHtml;
    $scope.currentDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.one);
    $scope.btnClick = function (selection){
      if(selection == "one"){
        $scope.currentDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.one);
      }
      else if(selection == "two"){
        $scope.currentDisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.two);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[$sce](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) service helps to render html content.

sample code

```
$scope.htmldisplay = $sce.trustAsHtml(data);
```

you have to inject $sce in your controller